# Error incompatible types: float cannot be converted to float[]

Tags: java

estoy haciendo un ejercicio con HashMaps
y necesito realizar lo siguiente.

Un profesor realiza varias secciones en la universidad y desea manejar las notas de sus alumnos en un único map.
Para ello ha definido la clase Calificaciones que tiene como atributo un map de las siguientes características:

```html
public class Calificacion {
    Map<String, Map<String, Vector <float[]>>> notas = new HashMap<>();
    private String seccion;
    private String matricula;
    float nota;
    
   public  Calificacion()
   {
       
   } 
     
   public Calificacion(String seccion,String matricula,float nota)
   {
       this.seccion=seccion;
       this.matricula=matricula;
       this.nota=nota;
   }
    
    public void agregarNotas(String seccion,String matricula, float nota)
    {
        Vector v1= new Vector();
        v1.add(nota);
        notas.put(seccion,matricula,(v1.add(nota)));
        
        System.out.println("Se agregó una nota "+ (notas));
         
    }
    
    
}
```

En base a lo anterior se pide:

1. Método int cantidadDeNotas(), que devuelve la cantidad de notas entre todas las secciones que ha puesto el profesor.
2. Método void agregarNota(string sección, string matricula, float nota), que agrega una nota al map de notas
3. Método void alumnosMasDeUnaSeccion() que imprime el número de matrícula de los alumnos que tienen clases en más de una sección con el profe.
4. Método imprimir que imprime:

a.  Número de Sección
b.  Por cada Sección, lista de alumnos con su promedio de notas

Lo que ocurre es que tengo error en la sintaxis al intentar agregar elementos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por favor su ayuda

Comment: cuando declaras el hashmap notas porque pones float[]? no deberia ir float solamente? le estas diciendo que en cada posicion del hash va un string y un array de floats.

Comment: no se entiende muy bien que queres hacer, agrega detalles a tu pregunta que es lo que queres lograr?

Comment: Hola buenas , acado de modificar, ahora les muestro que lo intento hacer de 2 maneras. de hecha la segunda manera me lo habia indicado alguien de esta plataforma pero da ese error de converted

Answer (score 0):

El error es que estas intentando agregar en tu map auxiliar un unico numero float, mientras que en la declaracion le dijiste que esperas un arreglo, puedes dejarlo asi pero al momento de agregar el objeto a tu map auxiliar hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

mapAux.put("MAT01",new float[]{(float)7.0});

o igual puedes cambiar la declaracion de tu map

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hola funciona pero cuando quiero imprimir me muestra esto  [{1={MAT0001=[F@567d299b}}]

Comment: Hola ahora ya edite mi consulta e ingrese mas detalle. Por favor su ayuda